# Change Date Time on my server and revert it back after testing

Tags: linux, date, time, timezone

I am using `date -s ".."` to change my date and time.

```
  date --s "Friday, March 11, 2016 12:00:00 PM IST"
```

I get the following error..I guess I am on Linux..Solaris..not sure what argument(plug) it uses internally for date..

```
 date: illegal option -- set
 usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
    date [-u] [+format]
    date -a [-]sss[.fff]
```

1. I want to change it to same date next month to perform testing.
2. I would like to revert it back to [IST](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/india/bangalore) post testing

What are my commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :)

```
date mmddhhmmyy

date 012111032016
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
date --set="2 OCT 2006 18:00:00" or date +%Y%m%d -s "20120418"
```

For the time to be in IST. You can try following

```
cd /etc
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/EST localtime
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Calcutta localtime
```

For temporary change in time zone

```
export TZ=Asia/Calcutta
```